# In Clock Event trigger, forumla fields are undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a trigger function called by a clock event.  I'm reading the values from the spread-sheet using range.getValues().  Instead of receiving formula result values in the resulting data array, I am seeing undefined where I have a formula.

How can I get the formulas to execute in this environment?

Here is an example.  This function is called every hour.  It should wait until the stock price exceeds $15.01.  Instead, it just emails me on the first hour telling me the price is "undefined" ...

```
/*
    run a script at a time or times you designate:

    From the Script Editor, choose Resources > Current script's triggers. You 
    see a panel with the message No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
    Click the link that says No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
    Under Run, select the function you want executed on schedule.
    Under Events, select Time-driven.
    On the first drop-down list that appears, select Hour timer
*/
function onHour() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("onHour");
  if(s == null) {
    s = ss.insertSheet("onHour", 1);
    s.appendRow(["EVENT","PROCESSED","EMAIL","SUBJECT","BODY"]);
  }
  //here are the column headers in the sheet onHour
  var EVENT=0; // first row (A2) has formula: =F2>15.01 ... cell F2 is: =GoogleFinance(G2; "price") ... G2 = PBI
  var PROCESSED=1; // this is empty (until later)
  var EMAIL=2; // my email
  var SUBJECT=3; //email subject
  var BODY=4;//has formula: =F2  ... email the price (however, email body = "undefined") 
  var range = s.getRange("A2:D"); //get everything above (leaving the D range open-ended works fine)
  var values = range.getValues(); 
  for(var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < values.length; rowIndex++) {
    var data = values[rowIndex];
    if(data[EVENT] && ! data[PROCESSED]) {//The first hour, cell data[EVENT] (A2) should be FALSE, but the IF condition evaluates to True ..
      //This emails me, but it should not have because the price has not reached $15.01
      MailApp.sendEmail(data[EMAIL], data[SUBJECT], data[BODY]);
      var cell = range.getCell(rowIndex+1, PROCESSED+1);
      //set the PROCESSED column (A3) to TRUE so I will only get 1 email
      cell.setValue(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood your question. Can you explain with a bit more words and an example, perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change s.getRange("A2:D") to s.getRange("A2:E")

getValue returns all formulas after evaluation as expected.  My range was not large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

To:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet id");
```

"add trigger" could do with a message - advising people to use openById rather than getActiveSpreadsheet

Comment: I did test it with the same results.  very clever .. I assume your concerned that I'm not getting a reference to the correct spread-sheet. I did notice that the code is able to update the correct spread-sheet. The code will put the TRUE value in the PROCESSED column. Because it getActiveSpreadsheet() does work in the trigger event environment I would prefer to keep it; in this way, the code is portable without needing to change the spread sheet id. I did not think of this as a possible breaking point though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like all your spreadsheets have an onHour sheet. Glad to see you sorted it out.

Comment: Only one so far.  But this is very generic so it should give the capability to report on any changing formula results.  Stocks are my first application.  I will change one thing so far, processed should be a timestamp instead of a boolean.